# indexOf() Fails if the String Contains a Carriage Return/Line Feed

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a database that is shared by a Windows program, and ASP pages. In the windows program a string was entered that comtains several CR/LF characters. It displays as expected in the textarea, but the javascript indexOf() method fails to find the string inside a message. The indexOf() method is working for any other string not containing the CR/LF characters. What do I need to do to find if the string is contained in the overall message?

For example, if the message contains:

> Your credit card statement will read "The Company".  Please use you order number when contacting us with questions about this invoice.
>
> Thank you for doing business with The Company.
>   Leave tape in place for 24 hours before removing.

and the string I want to match is:

> Your credit card statement will read "The Company".  Please use you order number when contacting us with questions about this invoice.
>
> Thank you for doing business with The Company.

indexOf() returns -1. I have verified that the string I am searching contains the string I want to find.

The code that is failing.

```
var index = message.indexOf(listbox.getItem(i).get_toolTip());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this happens, but the textarea is displays the embedded CRLF as expected, but just assigning the string to a variable and using `indexOf()` returns -1 every time the searched for string contains a CRLF. I resorted to using the `encodeURI()` method on the string being searched and the string being searched for prior to using `indexOf()` and that is working.

```
function messageContainsString(string) {
    var orderMessage = $get('<%=uxMessageOrderMessage.ClientID%>')
    if (orderMessage != null) {
        var message = encodeURI(orderMessage.textContent);
        if (message != null) {
            return message.indexOf(encodeURI(string)) > -1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So I know this is an old question, but I wanted to give a better answer than just URL encoding.

I arrived at this question with the same issue, but URL encoding did not fix my issue as Jac posted. However, it did allow me to troubleshoot and find the root cause.

The cause is that textarea only accepts a line feed (/n) and will convert any other newline types (/r/n and /r) to a line feed. So when searching using `indexOf` only put a line feed inside your strings and search for it to work.

In the example below, I also included the input element as well. The input element just removes any linebreaks inserted.

```js
let haystack = 'I contain a line break\nFind me';
let textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

textarea.value = haystack;

document.getElementById('rn').innerHTML = textarea.value.indexOf('\r\n');
document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = textarea.value.indexOf('\r');
document.getElementById('n').innerHTML = textarea.value.indexOf('\n');

let inpt = document.getElementById('input');

inpt.value = haystack;

document.getElementById('inrn').innerHTML = inpt.value.indexOf('\r\n');
document.getElementById('inr').innerHTML = inpt.value.indexOf('\r');
document.getElementById('inn').innerHTML = inpt.value.indexOf('\n');
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" cols="25" rows="3"></textarea>
<br>
<p>Place where line break occurs in textarea looking for \r\n: <span id="rn"></span></p>
<p>Place where line break occurs in textarea looking for \r: <span id="r"></span></p>
<p>Place where line break occurs in textarea looking for \n: <span id="n"></span></p>

<input type="text" id="input" />
<p>Place where line break occurs in textarea looking for \r\n: <span id="inrn"></span></p>
<p>Place where line break occurs in textarea looking for \r: <span id="inr"></span></p>
<p>Place where line break occurs in textarea looking for \n: <span id="inn"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CR/LF pairs are really there in the string, but when the HTML rendering engine lays out the paragraph, they're treated as embedded white space and ignored. When you search, however, JavaScript does *not* ignore the CR/LF characters.

Comment: If I use javascript to encode and display the innerText from the text area it shows %0D%0A characters in the string.

Comment: Yes, that would be CR/LF in the string. You didn't post your "get _toolTip()" function, so it's really hard to say what's going on.